# Using IIS' "http redirect" feature, allow non-trailing slash for sub-folders

Tags: iis, iis-7

The dialog looks like this:
[image]

Let's for argument's sake say that it says "https://cms.example.com/example".

The idea is that accessing "http://cms.example.com/" or "https://cms.example.com" should forward you to "https://cms.example.com/example". And it does.

However, if I try to access a different sub-folder of this domain, let's say "http://cms.example.com/other" it sends me to "https://cms.example.com/example/other". If I do "http://cms.example.com/other/" (note the trailing slash), I arrive where I expect to.

I can't expect our customers to be that finicky about the URLs their enter. How can I get IIS to behave more in line with my and my customers expectations? I realize that "/foo" and "/foo/" aren't the same thing to a computer, but non-techies don't and won't care.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the job with url rewrite.

look that post :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724455/iis-url-rewrite-add-trailing-slash-except-for-html-and-aspx

And this one :

http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#trailing-slash

Its a common use case for url rewrite .

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the current docs for IIS 7/8, but try adding the "redirection variables". Sounds like it's what you're missing.

cms.contoso.com$V$Q , right in the first text field of the dialog.

Here is [IIS 6 docs](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true), but they still work in later versions.